# Logstash JSON filter does not appear to be working with JDBC input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to index documents from a postgres view and into logstash via Elasticsearch. The statement part of my config file looks like this:

`select search_document FROM my_view;`

The next line in my config file is where I try to extract the value from the database call:

```
filter {
 json {
   source => "[search_document][value]"
  }
}
```

This should select the value of the column and then directly pipe it into Elasticsearch (or in this testing phase, stdout); however, it doesn't work correctly. I've tried several variations on the property access above, and it always inserts documents with "search_document" as a key and the rest of the JSON document as it's value.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I've updated my view to perform a `select search_document::text FROM my_view;` based on another answer I've found. The original type of the column is JSONB and the data in the row looks similar to this:

```
{ "value" : { "key_1": "hello", "key_2": "world" } }
```

Comment: Can you paste the format of the rows you are selecting?

Comment: Sure, see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try only specifying the the field you want to get like this:

```
filter {
 json {
   source => "value"
  }
}
```

The filter is supposed to be executed with every record so you shouldn't add the `search_document`

Comment: Is it possible that I need to use `json_encode` to format this from text to JSON first?